# jQuery not auto executing a command

Tags: jquery

Strangest thing... locally this auto scrolls, but once I upload it to my server, it doesn't auto scroll. The files are exactly the same. I even uploaded the entire working directory and it doesn't auto rotate. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#viewport').carousel('#previous', '#next');

    //The auto-scrolling function
    function slide(){
      $('#next').click();
    }
    //Launch the scroll every 2 seconds
    var intervalId = window.setInterval(slide, 6000);

    //On user click deactivate auto-scrolling
    $('#previous, #next').click(
    function(event){
      if(event.originalEvent){
          window.clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
    }
    );

});
```

I am using the plugin http://code.google.com/p/jquery-infinite-carousel/

Comment: Did you check the script file paths correctly set.

Comment: Paths are correctly set. Clicking on the #next and #previous triggers the right action so the jQuery is working, just the auto clicking does not seem to be executing for some reason.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the plugin. Can you debug using firebug or chrome?

Comment: The carousel plugin is working because it still rotates if I manually click an anchor with the id of next or previous. Just if I try to have it "auto" rotate, by clicking next automatically, that it doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like the auto click event is just not working. I have absolutely no clue why that would be the case. Is it security set up by a server that would inhibit an auto click event?

Comment: Try using  `setInterval(slide, 6000); ` without window.

Comment: @Jayantha - I really appreciate your help. That didn't seem to work either. It is so strange. It just doesn't want to do that click event for some reason.

Comment: The live website is: http://cannonbuildersinc.com/ 

The bottom 3 items (Bridge Construction, Commercial Building, Retaining Walls) are supposed to rotate to show another 3 divisions. Locally they work fine, they just aren't rotating on the server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12775/discussion-between-jayantha-and-jason)

Answer (score 1):

After spending all night last night trying to figure this out, I went to my hosting company to see if they were aware of any server security issues that might inhibit the autoclick. Their answer fixed the problem and was as follows:

"I had to update the "$('#next').click();" line to be "jQuery('#next').click();" because apparently there was some conflict going on and wordpress jquery is loading it with noConflict to true so that it will load with $ and also jQuery.

The reason it was not working inside Wordpress on live site was that there must have been some sort of conflict with another javascript library that is being loaded, jquery has a built in feature to avoid these conflicts. It is called 'noConflict' http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/  by calling this function which wordpress is already doing it makes it so that using 'jQuery' before function calls of jquery instead of '$' it will avoid those conflicts. This is because other libraries might utilize the '$' symbol as well. So to avoid possible conflicts in future updates we would suggest using the 'jQuery' call instead of '$'."

Answer (score 0):

try using $(window).load() instead of $(document).ready(), since it may take longer for your page to load on your server than on your localhost, and $(window).load() is called when the page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, that didn't fix the problem.